# Doctrine- nonaggregated column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have a syntax error in my query builder. When running on Windows 10 it works, but on Ubuntu it won't work. I think problem is with created/modified db fields.

Here is the code:

```
return $this->getMyRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a, MIN(a.numbers) AS min_no')
        ->where('a.item = :item')
        ->setParameter('item', $itemId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

which results in the error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bs.a0_.created' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You're doing a MIN so you should GROUP BY your query by your table "a"

Comment: ' When running on Win10 it works but on ubuntu won't work' - mysql versions/settings must be different.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. @leobrl